# How to workaround this ValueError: could not convert string to float?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to carry out a mathematical operation on all list objects:

```
swl = ['0', '0', '0', '', '', '', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0.25']
```

Mathematical operation: `sgu = 1 - swl`, where I want to format sgu as:

```
sgu_compact = ['3*1', '3*', '5*0', '0.75']
```

This is what I have:

```
sgu = []
for ii in range(0, int(len(swl))):
    if len(swl[ii]) == 0:
        sgu.append(swl[ii])
    else:
        sgu.append(1-float(swl[ii]))

sguflt = [float(x) for x in swl]
sgu2 = ['{:g}'.format(float('{:.6g}'.format(i))) for i in sgu]

sgu_compact = ['%s*' % len(l) * (len(l) > 1) + k for k, g in groupby(sgu2)
                for l in (list(g),)]

print sgu_compact
```

But I get `ValueError` due to empty list objects. Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: `swl` contains empty strings. You cannot convert an empty string to a `float`, but your list comprehension `sguflt = [float(x) for x in swl]` tries on every value anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can probably be optimized more, but as it stands seems to do what you said you wanted. Basically it just checks for and passes-though any empty string values encountered within each step.

```
from itertools import groupby

swl = ['0', '0', '0', '', '', '', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0.25']

sgu = []
for value in swl:
    if len(value):
        sgu.append(1 - float(value))
    else:
        sgu.append(value)

sguflt = [float(x) if x is not '' else '' for x in swl]

sgu2 = ['{:g}'.format(float('{:.6g}'.format(i))) if i is not '' else '' for i in sgu]

sgu_compact = ['%s*' % len(l) * (len(l) > 1) + k for k, g in groupby(sgu2)
                for l in (list(g),)]

print sgu_compact  # -> ['3*1', '3*', '5*0', '0.75']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just filter out the empty values:

```
swl = ['0', '0', '0', '', '', '', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0.25']
swl = [x for x in swl if len(x)]
```

Comment: No need to call `len()`. Just `swl = [x for x in swl if x]`. Empty strings are _falsey_

Comment: I need the empty strings in the new list though. The list format needs to be same as sgu_compact, so I cannot filter out empty objects.

Comment: @sool `swl = [float(x) if x else x for x in swl]`?